# Access Incron file from filesystem

Tags: debian, incron

Usually, to edit the Incron jobs, you run `incrontab -e` and that opens the file editor, ...
I want to be able to dynamically update the file by running something like `echo "<path> IN_CREATE <command> > incronfile`".
I can not find the files under /etc/incron.d/ ....
I am running on Debian10